# How to say "It started raining"

Tags: translation, verbs

I'm new to sentences with more than one verb.

Anyway, I think it should be something like 雨が降るの始める" read as "あめがふるのはじめる"
But from Google translate it seems that の is not necessary to turn 降る into a noun here.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **start** doing a verb just add はじめる to the masu stem of the verb e.g. 雨が降り始めた (it started raining). This should work for any verb where it makes sense to start doing something. Note that this is the transitive はじ**め**る rather than the intransitive はじ**ま**る

Similarly to **stop** doing a verb you add おわる to the masu stem. Note that this one uses the intransitive version rather than おえる.

There are other verbs you can add which have different nuances of starting/stopping, but I think these two are the most important ones to understand for now.